# strange behaviour of sql azure queries

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am experiencing weird behavior of SQL Azure database. While investigating why stored procedure suddenly started timing out (after several month of normal work without any problems), i found out following behavior (the code is from my SQL Server mgmt studio console, not from the stored proc, and actual table/field names replaced, but it illustrates the problem)

I'm running a very simple query

```
select * from dbo.mytable with (nolock) where field1 = 'somevalue'
```

The query just hangs there, indicator in status bar is spinning, status is "Executing query", and nothing happens. As an experiment i left it executing for hours and nothing happened. SQL Azure monitor doesn't show any deadlocks.

Similar query with filter by any other field executes immediately. But here's the interesting part - if I open another window in sql mgmgt studio and run the **same query** on the **same database** while the first one is hanging - it executes instantly without any issues. As soon as I cancel the query in the first window, if I run query in the second it stalls, and any other instance of it ran in parallel window executes fine. 
So far this has been happening with only one table and only if filtering by this specific field. Unfortunately, this is the main table in the database.

When i'm querying sys.dm_exec_requests it shows that query wait_type is SE_REPL_SLOW_SECONDARY_THROTTLE, and the status is initially *running* but then changes to *suspended*. Same query in the other window meanwhile is *running* with wait_type of SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD. But it is running, and the first is not.

Some background info: 
SQL Azure instance, 1GB, used space 35MB, 36 active connections
**mytable** - 61K rows, 15 columns, 30MB, has a clustered index on identity primary key, non-clustered index on date field. 
**field1** is of userd defined datatype derived from varchar(16) null, however field itself is defined as not null. 
there are other fields in mytable of the same datatype and also not null, and filtering by them shows no issues. 
mytable contains application's transaction information, and it has high insert rate. Inserts are happening in small transactions, there should be no locking issues. All reads outside the transactions are made with nolock hint.

It's not only select query that behaves that way, but any type of query on that table that involves that specific field.

I will try to create this database on the other server, copy the data and see if problem persists, but I have a feeling that it's in the database instance.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I found several other columns (so far in the same table) that exhibit the same problem - columns are of different types (int, varchar), so I think data type really doesn't matter

Comment: Another observation - even if one of those columns are mentioned in the select list and not in the where clause, query still hangs (but executes in parallel window)

Comment: So same day I opened ticket with Microsoft and sent them my logs. After several days they got back to me - turns out there was an issue during rolling upgrades in the datacenter where my instance of db was hosted, and connectivity and hung query problems were caused by failed upgrade. After upgrade was carried through problems with my queries hanging disappeared and not manifested since.